# Reuse iOS passcode / dialer keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to reuse the ios7 lockscreen keypad in my app? The user needs to create a pin to confirm transactions and I would like to use a similar screenlayout as the passcode keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a public class, you'll have to create your own.

Comment: Well, i expected that. But i thought i should ask before i build my own

Comment: You also need to be aware that Apple will reject your app if your custom passcode interface to closely resembles Apples.